# Как в миллисекунды перевести введенную дату 01.02.1994?

Tags: javascript

Как в миллисекунды перевести введенную дату в таком формате 01.02.1994?

Comment: наверное стоит сказать что такое 01 и 02. где тут месяц а где день

Comment: Также необходимо сказать, в миллисекунды относительно чего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(+new Date('01.02.1994'))
```

Comment: Хм, в FF 47 на линуксе этот код отдаёт NaN, в то время как в Хроме всё корректно. Почему так?

Comment: @iksuy Потому что FF не понимает разделители `.`:
`>> console.log(new Date('01.02.1994'))
< Invalid Date 
>>console.log(new Date('01-02-1994'))
< Invalid Date
>> console.log(+new Date('01/02/1994'))
< 757458000000
`

Comment: Да, я поигрался с разными форматами дат и понял это. Странно конечно.

Comment: @iksuy Просто firefox сделали по [стандарту](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), а chrome сделали более гибкий парсер